# Calling Activities from different package

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities from two different packages, I wish to call an activity in Package2 from package1
To do so i used the following,

```
Intent intentDeviceTest = new Intent();                
intentDeviceTest.setComponent(new ComponentName("chat.client.gui","chat.client.gui.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intentDeviceTest);
```

This shows an error that the activity is not found, add this to manifest.

But it works fine when i call it in this way,

```
Intent intentDeviceTest = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainActivity.class);      
startActivity(intentDeviceTest);
```

Whats the mistake in the above method!

Comment: see this [launch activities from different package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741857/launch-activities-from-different-package)

Answer (score 0):

I always use the second form in my apps.  It is simpler, clearer and shorter.

```
// Assumes that this is done from within an Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);  
startActivity(intent);
```

But I think the problem with the first form is that you specified the package again in the second parameter.  You only need the class name:

```
Intent intentDeviceTest = new Intent();                
intentDeviceTest.setComponent(new ComponentName("chat.client.gui", "MainActivity"));
startActivity(intentDeviceTest);
```

Look at the first constructor in this for a reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html

Comment: even i do the first one you mentioned, but these activities are in different package, so...