# I need to transfer data from an android native application to hybrid android application through JSON data in a single device

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to transfer data from an android native application to a hybrid android application through JSON data in a single device.

example :

{
"id" : "27g38yvr8vr84"
"name" : "3984h93urnf9uwbef8yew"
"lat" : "34.35"
"long" : "29.45"
"device_id" : "8734gf83g8f384g"
"mac_id" : "387gf83gf83b48bf"
}

I need to transfer this data to another application (hybrid) and that will give me reponse in JSON too.

How can I receive that JSON data?
Any code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly you mean you are transferring data from native app to hibrid app? How exactly are you doing that?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar on click of a button opening that application which is already installed in the device. After opening that application I need to pass the data to that application through JSON values which I have mentioned format in the above.

Comment: @dinkar_kumar I want to know how is it possible ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741857/launch-activities-from-different-package